# What's the meaning of "large hug" in definition of "bearhug"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Context:

> I have an uncle who is huge and any time he hugs anyone in the family, it's so tight that they are almost choked. We call this the *bearhug* among the family.

Researching the term, and seeing its origins in wrestling

> a wrestling hold in which the arms are
>   locked tightly round an opponent's
>   chest and arms

My question is [on this definition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bear%20hug)

> any especially large, tight or
>   enthusiastic hug, usually friendly

Does the **large** here imply the hugging person is bigger and stronger than the hug-ee (like a bear) or is it the length of time of the hug, or something else?

Does the usage give the impression of [Hagrid from Harry Potter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubeus_Hagrid)? It does to me, but I don't know if thats the right idea.

Comment: This isn't really a question about English so much as a question about hugs.

Comment: @Jon: I've added as much context to make it a question about the approriate usage of *bearhug*. Does it apply if both people are tiny or same-sized?

Comment: @Jon: Should have been asked on Hugs.SE.  Voting to migrate... ;)

Comment: @drm: I did flag the mods to delete this as off-topic - but they've chosen to leave it here. Oh the humiliation :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It implies they are larger than you, but "enthusiastic" can imply the length of time. The hugger doesn't necessarily have to be bear-like, but it definitely helps.

Comment: I'd say enthusiastic is accurate enough, and it _could_ imply length of time, but there are so many other things that can go along with an "enthusiastic" hug, including general body posture, facial expressions, words and tones used, the precise position of arms (perhaps pinning someone's arms, not out of threat, but rather more like saying to the person, "I'm so enthusiastic, I'm going to give you a hug whether you want one or not"), and a few others...

Answer (score 3):

"Large hug" here is the same as in "big hug". ["Big"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/big) has the meaning of "enthusiastic", so, a "large hug" is an enthusiastic hug.

> (informal, with on) Enthusiastic